# How do I disable snake_case naming style warning in ALE?

Tags: filetype-python, plugin-ale

I want to disable annoying snake_case naming style warning:

```
invalid-name: Variable name "xxx" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style
```

Tried `:help` and `grep snake_case`, but didn't get anything.

Comment: You are making a category error, here. ALE is just a front-end for various external tools and it is one of those external tools that is producing the warning, not ALE itself, and certainly not Vim, so this is way off-topic. Figure out which tool produces the warning, then figure out how to tell it to shut up, then figure out if it has to be done via ALE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun fact: ALE doesn't check your code. ALE doesn't produce any warnings.
What ALE does do, it *runs code checkers* that do the actual code checking and aggregates their output. Like that co-worker you hate, it let's others do the work and passes the results as its own.

The question doesn't say but it's pretty obvious this one's about Python.

The first (and almost only) ALE command you need to know is `:ALEInfo`. It will show which tools were run and the warnings they reported. It's a lot of text and you will need to scroll down for a bit.

I wrote a line of Python code, ran `:ALEInfo` and saw

```
C0103 (invalid-name) Variable name "camelCase" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style
```

reported by `pylint`.

You can Google how to shut `pylint` up.
I'll show two ways. You can set a variable for ALE to forward to `pylint`

```
:let g:ale_python_pylint_options='--disable=C0103'
```

which will work within Vim for all your Python code.

The alternative is to create a simple `.pylintrc` like this one

```ini
[SECTION MANDATORY BUT IGNORED]

disable=C0103
```

This can be per-project or globally and will prevent the warning independently from Vim.

Either way, the warning is gone.

### When in Python, do as the Pythons do

I'd like to emphasize that [PEP-8 demands snake_case](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) so it's better to use snake_case identifiers instead of disabling the warning. If it was my repo, I'd bluntly reject such code.